reloading a page in Svelte5 + svelteKit returns 500 Internal server error, but not when following a link
I have a page on my site that is at the route routes/gallery in SvelteKit, and clicking on a a tag links to it correctly.  But when I reload the page with the browser reload button, I get a 500 internal server error.
This has started occurring after migrating from Svelte 4 to Svelte 5.

There should be server-side rendering errors in the console running the dev server. Show the errors and the code for the page, otherwise this will likely be closed. Try to first create a minimal reproduction by removing everything that is not causing the error.
